# Selective CSS rules

Tags: css

I am working on service which allows third parties to upload HTML snippets. In some of these snippets there may be links to CSS files or inline CSS. The service has it's own CSS files.

Is there any way, besides iFrames, which would allow me to indicate that specific CSS files are only to be applied to the specific HTML elements and not the whole page?

Comment: maybe using <style scoped>@import url(yourcssfile);</style> within the snippet itself.  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/style#Example_B

Comment: Very interesting idea, I was not aware of this. I'm not sure how practical it would be considering that I don't want users to scope their HTML, but it's something I'm going to investigate further

Comment: scoped browser support isn't great but this jquery plugin may help.  https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no solution I've found on the interwebs seems to work for me, so I just had to scrap the idea of using scoped CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could download the CSS-files, prepend some `#unique-container-identifier` to all rules within it and just embed the markup into your page, inside a container with the ID previously assigned.

That'll leave you with a problem of your own, "real rules", ruining things inside those boxes though...